# HTML Dropdown is not showing after opened with Live Server, coded in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have created a code in javascript that will show a dropdown of color and age selection. However after I ran the code, the dropdown option was not showing. But, it still can be chosen and recorded the correct value.

the following is the screenshot of the programmed:

Dropdown for age is empty:

[image: Dropdown for age is empty]

Dropdown for color is empty:

[image: Dropdown for color is empty]

The following is the code:

```js
console.log("Hello world");

var ageSelect = document.getElementById("age");
var ageNumber = 12;
var colorSelect = document.getElementById("color")
var colorArray = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Black'];

let data = {};

for (let i = ageNumber; i < 30; i++){
    var opt = i.toString();
    var opt = i;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.context = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    ageSelect.appendChild(el);
}

for (var j = 0; j < colorArray.length; j++){
    var cl = document.createElement("option");
    cl.context = colorArray[j];
    cl.value = colorArray[j];
    colorSelect.appendChild(cl);
}

function capitalize() {
    var nameString = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var splitString = nameString.split(" ")
    var outputString = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < splitString.length; n++){
        if (n != 0){
            outputString = outputString + " "
        }
        outputString = outputString + splitString[n].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitString[n].slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    document.getElementById("username").value = outputString

}

document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function click(){
    data.name = document.getElementById("username").value;
    data.age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    data.color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    console.table(data) 

});
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onchange="capitalize();"><br>
Age: <select id="age" name="age"></select><br>
Favorite Color: <select id="color" name="color"></select><br>
<button type="button" id="but">Submit</button>
```

Comment: `el.context = opt;` - why are you trying to set a `context` property on the `option` elements you are creating? That should be `text`.

Comment: You gave the `<option>` elements *values*, but no *text*.  Are you just looking for `el.textContent = opt;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is:
In the age selection loop, the el.context should be el.textContent to set the text content of the option elements correctly and same in color

```js
console.log("Hello world");

var ageSelect = document.getElementById("age");
var ageNumber = 12;
var colorSelect = document.getElementById("color")
var colorArray = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Black'];

let data = {};

for (let i = ageNumber; i < 30; i++){
    var opt = i.toString();
    var opt = i;
    var el = document.createElement("option");
    el.textContent = opt;
    el.value = opt;
    ageSelect.appendChild(el);
}

for (var j = 0; j < colorArray.length; j++){
    var cl = document.createElement("option");
    cl.textContent = colorArray[j];
    cl.value = colorArray[j];
    colorSelect.appendChild(cl);
}

function capitalize() {
    var nameString = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var splitString = nameString.split(" ")
    var outputString = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < splitString.length; n++){
        if (n != 0){
            outputString = outputString + " "
        }
        outputString = outputString + splitString[n].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitString[n].slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }

    document.getElementById("username").value = outputString

}

document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click", function click(){
    data.name = document.getElementById("username").value;
    data.age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    data.color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    console.table(data) 

});
```

```html
Name: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" onchange="capitalize();"><br>
Age: <select id="age" name="age"></select><br>
Favorite Color: <select id="color" name="color"></select><br>
<button type="button" id="but">Submit</button>
```